# Specman/e constraint (for each in) iteration

Tags: aop, verification, specman, e

Can I iterate through only a part of a list in e, in a constraint.
For example, this code will go through the whole layer_l list:

```
<'

struct layer_s {
  a : int;
    keep soft a == 3;
};

struct layer_gen_s {
  n_layers : int;
    keep soft n_layers == 8;
  layer_l  : list of layer_s;
    keep layer_l.size() == read_only(n_layers);
};

extend sys {
  layer_gen : layer_gen_s;     

  run() is also {
    messagef(LOW, "n_layers = %0d", layer_gen.n_layers);
    for each in layer_gen.layer_l{
      messagef(LOW, "layer[%2d]: a = %0d", index, it.a);
    };
  };
};

-- this will go through all layer_l
extend layer_gen_s {    
  keep for each (layer) using index (i) in layer_l {
    layer.a == 7;
  };
};
```

But, I would like to only iterate the for each in through, for example, 2 items. I tried the code below, but it doesn't work:

```
-- this produces an error
extend layer_gen_s {    
  keep for each (layer) using index (i) in [layer_l.all(index < 2)] {
    layer.a == 7;
  };
};
```

Also I don't want to use implication, so this is not what I want:

```
-- not what I want, I want to specify directly in iterated list
extend layer_gen_s {    
  keep for each (layer) using index (i) in layer_l {
    (i < 2) => {
      layer.a == 7;
    };
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the list slicing operator doesn't work either, because the `path` in a `for..each` constraint is limited to a simple `path` (e.g. a list variable). The following doesn't work either:

```
keep for each (layer) using index (i) in layer_l[0..2] {
  //...
};
```

This is a Specman limitation.

To force looping over a sub-list your only bet is to create that sub-list as a separate variable:

```
layer_subl: list of layer_s;
keep layer_subl.size() == 3;
keep for each (layer) using index (i) in layer_subl {
  layer == layer_l[i];
};
```

Now you can loop on only the first 3 elements within your `for..each` constraint:

```
keep for each (layer) in layer_subl {
  layer.a == 7;
};
```

This avoids using implication inside the constraint. Whether this is worth is for you to decide. Also note that the lists will contain the **same** objects (this is good). No extra `struct` objects get created.

Creation of the sub-list like this is boilerplate code that could be handled by the tool itself. This would make the code much more concise and readable. You could contact your vendor and request this feature.

Comment: When you say lists will contain the same objects, do you mean that layer_subl will behave like a pointer to layer_l and not create additional objects? So when I constrain layer_subl, essentially, I will be constraining a subset of layer_l?

Comment: @evilpascal Yes. The `==` operator for `structs` means 'reference equality', i.e. 'identity'.

Comment: @evilpascal Also, e macros are very powerful. It's probably possible to write a `define as computed` macro that expands `keep for each (layer) in layer_l[0..2]` to exactly the code I provided, thus extending the language.

Comment: In fact, it will not create new objects, but it will create a new list: `layer_subl` will be a separate list that will contain pointers from the original list. If you concern about performance, keep in mind that lists (even if their elements are pointers) themselves have memory overhead.